# PDO not found error even tho it is installed and enabled in php.ini

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces

I have a small database class and I'm trying to use `PDO` to connect to my database but I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\lib\PDO' not found in /var/www/html/app/lib/DB.php:11

I checked if `PDO` is enabled using this code:

```
if ( extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ) {
    exit('yes');
}
```

And the output is "yes".

I've also checked my `php.ini` and i do have this line (no semi-column):

```
extension=pdo_mysql
```

This is my `DB.php` code:

```
namespace app\lib;

class DB{

    private static $instance = null;
    public $pdo;

    private function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db', 'user', 'password');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function instance(){

        if(!isset(self::$instance)){
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

And this is my autoloader(`init.php`) file:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

spl_autoload_register(function($namespace){
    $path = dirname(__FILE__) . DS . str_replace('\\', DS, $namespace . '.php');

    if(file_exists($path)){
        require_once $path;
    }
});
```

This is how i am trying to set a new `DB` connection:

```
require_once 'init.php';

$db = app\lib\DB::instance();
```

P.S: Pdo works if i don't use namespaces and go for procedural code:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db', 
'user', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pdo works if i don't use namespaces

This is the key to your solution. `PDO` is a class in PHP. All class names should be fully qualified, otherwise PHP will look for that class' definition only in the current namespace. To use PDO in any other namespace than global you would need to specify the global namespace with the help of a single `\`

```
$this->pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db', 'user', 'password');
```

Side note. The way you are creating the PDO instance is not the recommended one. You should specify the charset as well as enable PDO error reporting.

```
$this->pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4', 'user', 'password', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
]);
```

**Never catch exceptions, just to `die/exit`**. Either let the exceptions bubble up, or handle them properly. Displaying the error message to the user manually is a potential security issue.

Comment: thank you! It worked :O! Off-topic can you point me a good article for proper error handling? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! :D Now i have another problem with pdo but this time when i'm running a command (even tho pdo_mysql is enabled in cli ini just like in apache2 ini) i get this error: `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' `. Should i post another question?

Comment: @emma Please google that error message, first. There is plenty of answers for this. If you still can't find it on the web, then ask another question.

Comment: Solved! :D Thank you so much for taking time off to answer my question/s!!